# Как инициализировать пару при её создании в С++?

Tags: c++, stl, инициализация

Пример инициализации обычных переменных и последовательностей, если не совсем уловили контекст вопроса:

```
int a = 2;
int a [] = {2,3,4,5};
vector <int> a = {2,3,4,5};


pair <int,int> a = {?};
```

Answer (score 3):

[Можете посмотреть документацию здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/)

В вашем случае можно сделать вот так:

```
pair<int, int> p = make_pair<int, int>(1, 2);
pair<int, int> arr[] = { {1,2}, {2,4}, {2,4} };
vector <pair<int, int>> vec = { {1,2}, {2,4}, {2,4} };
```

Если вы работаете с массивом, то советую рассмотреть еще контейнеры std::array
и std::vector.

Answer (score 3):

C++98

```
const std::pair<int, int> p(1, 2);
const std::pair<int, int> p = std::make_pair(1, 2);
```

C++11

```
const std::pair<int, int> p = {1, 2};
const std::pair<int, int> p({1, 2});
const std::pair<int, int> p{1, 2};
```

Comment: В вопросе не было описано, но как инициализировать массив пар?